# Estimates of integral of $|x|^{-1}$ over cubes in $\mathbb{R}^n, n > 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Question: Let $n > 1$ and for any $d > 1$ show there exists $C_d >1$ so that $\int_{Q_d} |x|^{-1}\, dx \leq C_d \int_Q |x|^{-1}\, dx $ for any cube $Q \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ where $Q_d$ is the concentric cube with $d$ times length as $Q$ and $|x|$ being the Euclidean norm.

Attempt: I believe we can take $C_d = d$. Assuming that $Q = [0,1]^n$ so $Q_d = [0,d]^n$ then for any $x \in Q$ we have $|x| \leq \sqrt{n}$ and similarly for any $x \in Q_d$ we have $|x| \leq d\sqrt{n}$. Using the layer-cake representation of the integral we have
\begin{align}
\int_Q |x|^{-1}\, dx &= \int_0^\infty |\{x \in Q \colon |x|^{-1} > t\}|\, dt = \int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}^\infty \left|\left\{x \in Q \colon |x| < \frac{1}{t} \right\} \right|\, dt\\
\int_{Q_d} |x|^{-1}\, dx &= \int_0^\infty |\{x \in Q_d \colon |x|^{-1} > t\}|\, dt = \int_{\frac{1}{d\sqrt{n}}}^\infty \left|\left\{x \in Q_d \colon |x| < \frac{1}{t} \right\} \right|\, dt.
\end{align}
and by a change of variable
\begin{align}
\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}^\infty \left|\left\{x \in Q \colon |x| < \frac{1}{t} \right\} \right|\, dt &= \int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}^\infty \left|\left\{ x \in Q \colon |dx| < \frac{d}{t}\right\} \right|\, d t\\
&= \int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}^\infty \left| \left\{ x \in Q_d \colon |x| < \frac{d}{t} \right\} \right|\, dt\\
&= d \cdot \int_{\frac{1}{d\sqrt{n}}}^\infty \left|\left\{x \in Q_d \colon |x| < \frac{1}{t} \right\} \right|\, dt.
\end{align}
hence $\int_Q |x|^{-1}\, dx = d \int_{Q_d} |x|^{-1}\, dx$ but $d >1$. May I know why this method does not work? Or are there any gaps in my proof? Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: I believe this is just a change of variable.

Comment: You can set $x=dy$ in the original integral over $Q_d$. The resulting integral is one over the unit cube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach which is morally just changing variables.

Let $c$ be the center of $Q_d$, and note that for $x\in Q_d$, $|x|\approx c$ for appropriate implied dimensional constants. Hence, $\int_{Q_d}|x|^{-1}\,dx \le c_d \cdot m(Q_d)c^{-1}$. By the way Lebesgue measure plays with dilation, this is nothing but $C_d \cdot m(Q)c^{-1}$. Since $|x|\approx c^{-1}$ on $Q$, we have $m(Q)c^{-1} \approx \int_Q|x|^{-1}\,dx$, which finishes the proof.

In case the center of $Q$ is $0$, we can make the same argument based on a subcube of $Q$ (and $Q_d$).

Comment: thank you for the hints, however I can't seem to get the bound to be larger than $1$ and using the layer-cake representation my answer doesn't seem to make sense since the integrand over $Q_d$ is at least greater than the integrand over $Q$.